# What role does a suffix plays in the meaning of an adjective?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, suffixes

I have seen the variants of different adjectives with different suffices being used in a sentence. Some of them are as:

[Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/select)

> The opera was seen by a small and highly **select** audience.
>   He joined his **select** team of young Intelligence operatives.
>   I am highly **selective** about my food.

Some other examples I have come across are:

> The **modulation** frequency is kept high.
>   The **modulating** frequency is kept high.
>
> My **pursuing** year is 4th year.
>   My **persuasion** year is 4th year.

I find these gerund adjectives and their variants with **ion** suffix very confusing.

Comment: Are you sure about "pursuing" and "persuasion"? Where have you come across this?

Comment: @laugh I have not really come across **persuasion**. I just found the gerund adjective **pursuing** a bit confusing and suggested an alternative. See it seems as if "pursuing year" has "pursuing" as a verb as in **cutting wood**, **cutting** is a verb and not an adjective.

Comment: But it seems the confusion clears when I insert an article as **cutting a wood**.

Comment: This gerund adjective phrase **pursuing year** could also contain an article if **pursuing** had been a verb here. I don't think this all has to do anything with mediopassive voice at all.

Comment: I guess you mean suffixes, but your question is very, very broad. A suffix is not an addition to an adjective. It is an "addition" to a word root. By the way, my pursuing year there doesn't make sense. My pursuing year?? An ensuing year, yes. One learns nouns and adjectives separately.  You cannot always predict them so easily.

Comment: By the way, selective and select are two different adjectives.

Comment: Pursuing year is an uncommon combination and I suspect it doesn't mean what you think it means. Persuation is a completely unrelated word, it comes from persuade, not pursue, and has a different meaning altogether, that doesn't connect to "year" in any way. I suggest using a dictionary to understand the meaning of these words, and to find the correct word for your intent (is that possibly "graduation year"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the suffix often changes the meaning and usage of the adjective, but not necessarily in any predictable way.  For example, consider all the adjectives built from "sense":

> - sensual
> - sensuous
> - sensitive
> - sensational
> - senseless
> - sensible
> - sensory
> - sensorial
> - sensualized
> - sensualistic
> - sensationalized

While all of these are related, the meaning of each is somewhat different, and can only be learned from context.  "Sensual" and "sensuous", for example, are slightly different in a way that many native speakers might not know:

> [**Sensual**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensual) (adj): *relating to or consisting in the gratification of the senses or the indulgence of appetite*
>
> [**Sensuous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensuous) (adj): *of or relating to the senses or sensible objects, having strong sensory appeal*

Some suffixes have consistent meaning, for example "-ized" generally means "became like" or "make like"

> It is a **sensational** headline (it's a headline designed to arouse strong sensations)
>
> It is a **sensationalized** headline (it's been made sensational by someone or something)

However this doesn't account for nuance.  For example "idealized" suggests a *false* or *unrealistic* ideal.

> She was an **ideal** leader (she represented the best qualities of a leader)
>
> She was an **idealized** leader  (she was believed to be an ideal leader, but this was more wishful thinking than reality)

So the solution is to read a lot to learn the meaning of adjectives like these *in context*, and pick up the patterns.

It's much too broad a question to list the meanings of every possible adjective suffix.  Many of your examples are not correct -- *modulation* is a noun, *pursuing year* is not idiomatic, *persuasion* is a noun, and *pursuing* and *persuasion* are not related -- but if you have questions about any specific suffix, that we could probably answer.

[List of common adjective suffixes and their meanings](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adj-forms.html)

Comment: If I would rather ask about the difference between **select** and **selective** both being used as adjectives.

Comment: Also I would like you to suggest a proper adjective for the word **modulate** for the above examples.

Comment: Sadly, it seems "select" and "selective" simply have different meanings, unrelated to the suffix.  *Select* means "having a unique, noteworthy quality" while *selective* means "picky".  Meanwhile *distinct* means "easily distinguished from others" with *distinctive* as a near synonym, applied to a particular characteristic of a person or thing.  The "-ive" suffix tells us little.

Answer (score 0):

Suffix -ion is mostly seen in **nouns** not **adjectives**. For example, regulat**ion**(noun) purificat**ion**(noun), etc.

'Selective' is an adjective in your question; moreover, other sentences in your examples are grammatically incorrect such as, 'select' supposedly selected(verb, past tense) in *highly select team*.

Second example is not correct in terms of grammar, should be ->he has joined a/the selected team of young-intelligent(adjective) operatives... so on and so forth...

Comment: **'Selective' is an adjective in your question; moreover, other sentences in your examples are grammatically incorrect such as, 'select' supposedly selected(verb, past tense) in highly select team.** I have attached the source, these examples are given in the online Oxford dictionary. So that means Oxford dictionary have put ungrammatical sentences?

Comment: As far as I can understand it, those oxford examples are quoted... an excerpt from something. That I cannot answer simply because British english may mean other things(select) beside from what it is used to be.

Comment: @JohnArvin "A **select** team of crack troops" is perfectly valid American English, see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/select  under the "American" or "Business" tabs.